# How to do a SELECT using cascade ranking in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, ranking

I know how to structure a SELECT statement to give the top 10 ranked entries by count of a list of product codes and sub-models, but how to go one level deeper on ranking?  That is to list the top 5 ranked (by count) sub-models for each of the top 10 ranked models?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE RANKTEST ( 
"MODEL"    VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),  
"SUBMODEL" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)  ) ; 

insert into ranktest values('A100','R1');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R1');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R1');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R1');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R2');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R2');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R3');
insert into ranktest values('A100','R4');
insert into ranktest values('A103','R5');
insert into ranktest values('A103','R5');
insert into ranktest values('A103','R5');
insert into ranktest values('A103','R5');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X1');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X1');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X1');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X2');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X2');
insert into ranktest values('A103','X3');
insert into ranktest values('A104','R1');
insert into ranktest values('A104','R2');
insert into ranktest values('A105','R2');
insert into ranktest values('A105','R3');
insert into ranktest values('A105','R4');
commit;


SELECT model,
   cnt,
   rank
FROM
  (SELECT model,
     COUNT(*)  AS cnt,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY COUNT(model) DESC) AS rank
  FROM
  ( SELECT * FROM ranktest )
  GROUP BY model )
  WHERE rank <=3;

  This gives the result:

MODEL  CNT    RANK
A103   10      1
A100    8      2
A105    3      3
```

I am looking for the SELECT syntax to show the top 2 ranked submodels for the top 3 ranked models

```
MODEL SUBMODEL CNT RANK SUB-COUNT SUB-RANK
A103    R5      10   1      4        1  
A103    X1      10   1      3        2
A100    R1       8   2      4        1
A100    R2       8   2      2        2
A105    R2       3   3      1        1
A105    R3       3   3      1        1
A105    R4       3   3      1        1
```

(The sub-rank for Model A105 and all its sub-models is a result of using DENSE_RANK(), at least as I think it should look.)

Comment: please, share you table definition with data, and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926da/7)

I would first calculate the count of models and submodels.

**Query 1**:

```
select model_, submodel_, 
       count(*) submodel_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by model_) model_count
from ranktest
group by model_, submodel_
order by 1,2,3 desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926da/7/0)**:

```
| MODEL_ | SUBMODEL_ | SUBMODEL_COUNT | MODEL_COUNT |
|--------|-----------|----------------|-------------|
|   A100 |        R1 |              4 |           8 |
|   A100 |        R2 |              2 |           8 |
|   A100 |        R3 |              1 |           8 |
|   A100 |        R4 |              1 |           8 |
|   A103 |        R5 |              4 |          10 |
|   A103 |        X1 |              3 |          10 |
|   A103 |        X2 |              2 |          10 |
|   A103 |        X3 |              1 |          10 |
|   A104 |        R1 |              1 |           2 |
|   A104 |        R2 |              1 |           2 |
|   A105 |        R2 |              1 |           3 |
|   A105 |        R3 |              1 |           3 |
|   A105 |        R4 |              1 |           3 |
```

And then use the dense_rank function to assign ranks.

**Query 2**:

```
select model_, submodel_, model_count, submodel_count, 
       dense_rank() over (order by model_count desc) model_rank,
       dense_rank() over (partition by model_ order by submodel_count desc) submodel_rank
from (
select model_, submodel_, 
       count(*) submodel_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by model_) model_count
from ranktest
group by model_, submodel_
)
order by 1,2,5,6
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926da/7/1)**:

```
| MODEL_ | SUBMODEL_ | MODEL_COUNT | SUBMODEL_COUNT | MODEL_RANK | SUBMODEL_RANK |
|--------|-----------|-------------|----------------|------------|---------------|
|   A100 |        R1 |           8 |              4 |          2 |             1 |
|   A100 |        R2 |           8 |              2 |          2 |             2 |
|   A100 |        R3 |           8 |              1 |          2 |             3 |
|   A100 |        R4 |           8 |              1 |          2 |             3 |
|   A103 |        R5 |          10 |              4 |          1 |             1 |
|   A103 |        X1 |          10 |              3 |          1 |             2 |
|   A103 |        X2 |          10 |              2 |          1 |             3 |
|   A103 |        X3 |          10 |              1 |          1 |             4 |
|   A104 |        R1 |           2 |              1 |          4 |             1 |
|   A104 |        R2 |           2 |              1 |          4 |             1 |
|   A105 |        R2 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
|   A105 |        R3 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
|   A105 |        R4 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
```

Finally, filter out the top models and submodels.

**Query 3**:

```
select model_, submodel_, model_count, submodel_count,
       model_rank, submodel_rank
from (
select model_, submodel_, model_count, submodel_count, 
       dense_rank() over (order by model_count desc) model_rank,
       dense_rank() over (partition by model_ order by submodel_count desc) submodel_rank
from (
select model_, submodel_, 
       count(*) submodel_count,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by model_) model_count
from ranktest
group by model_, submodel_
)
)
where model_rank <=3 and submodel_rank <=2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/926da/7/2)**:

```
| MODEL_ | SUBMODEL_ | MODEL_COUNT | SUBMODEL_COUNT | MODEL_RANK | SUBMODEL_RANK |
|--------|-----------|-------------|----------------|------------|---------------|
|   A103 |        R5 |          10 |              4 |          1 |             1 |
|   A103 |        X1 |          10 |              3 |          1 |             2 |
|   A100 |        R1 |           8 |              4 |          2 |             1 |
|   A100 |        R2 |           8 |              2 |          2 |             2 |
|   A105 |        R2 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
|   A105 |        R4 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
|   A105 |        R3 |           3 |              1 |          3 |             1 |
```

Comment: Exactly! And I really appreciate the incremental answer.  Always learning.